# Cant import facebook Session class in android in android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am newbie to android and working on a demo for getting facebook profilel info after login,I have successfully implemented login and want to fetch profile info,i got the code,But while adding profile info it's fail to import necessary classes(Session),can anybudy help me for this.
**java**

```
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

.
.
.
.
.


private Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI,
                                       StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity).
                setPermissions(permissions).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.
                SSO_WITH_FALLBACK).setCallback(callback).
                setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + session);
        if (session == null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, fbStatusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) || allowLoginUI) {
                session.openForRead(openRequest);
                return session;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working code for FACEBOOK INTEGRATION:

1) Create one xml: fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) Java Class i.e. MainFragment.java

```
package example.com.facebook_integration;

/**
 * Created by dinesh sharma on 2/22/2016.
 */

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import net.simplifiedcoding.androidlogin.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView textView;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };

    public MainFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                displayMessage(newProfile);
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_likes");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday","user_likes","user_friends"));

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                            {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                try
                                {
                                    // Application code
                                    System.out.println("JSONRESPOMSEEE "+response.toString());

                                    String email = object.getString("email");
                                    String birthday = object.getString("birthday"); // 01/31/1980 format
                                    String name = object.getString("name");
                                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                    Uri uri=(Uri)profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200);
                                    System.out.println("Email  "+email+" Birthday "+birthday+name);
                                    System.out.println("Email  " + uri);
                                    final ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();


                                    new GraphRequest(
                                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                            "/me/likes",
                                            null,
                                            HttpMethod.GET,
                                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                                    try {
                                                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                                                        JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                                                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                                                            JSONObject likes = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                            String likeId = likes.getString("id");
                                                            String likeName = likes.getString("name");
                                                            String likeCreatedTime = likes.getString("created_time");
                                                            arrayList.add("Page Name "+likeName+" Time= "+likeCreatedTime+" ID= "+likeId);
                                                            System.out.println("My Name " + likeName + " " + likeCreatedTime);
                                                        }
                                                        System.out.println("ArrayList mine "+arrayList);
                                                        System.out.println("ArrayList mine size "+arrayList.size());


                                                    }
                                                    catch(Exception e)
                                                    {
                                                        System.out.println("My Exception "+e);
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                    ).executeAsync();



                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void displayMessage(Profile profile) {
        if(profile != null){
            textView.setText(profile.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
    }

}
```

3) Create one more xml: activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="example.com.facebook_integration.MainFragment"
        ></fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

4) Create your MainActivity.java

```
package example.com.facebook_integration;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import net.simplifiedcoding.androidlogin.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

See this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/login-with-facebook-android-studio-using-facebook-sdk-4/

But i have done all the important changes in my code you can use this code after following all the steps from above link.